# Set maximum number of visible rows for listview

Tags: android

Is there a way for setting a number of maximum visible rows for a listview?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to handle this yourself?  ListView already optimizes hiding/showing Views within a ListView to maximize performance. If it's for another reason can you elaborate on what exactly you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want this limit to be 3, for example. After that, the list should be scrollable. It's about the application's specifications. It wasn't my idea.

Comment: I could create a custom listview, and set the height there, dynamically. I was wondering if there is a simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

have done it, I used custom adapter and then there i set the height of the row the to my desired height. by setting up the height of the row in listview i can set how many rows can be initially displayed and others are scrollable, where i place the listview inside a layout(relative or linear) and then i setup the height of the layout, with the multiple of how many rows do you want to be seen, ei row height is 50dp your layout height should be 150dp if you want 3 visible rows.

Comment: i hope this link will help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057596/maximize-visible-rows-in-a-listview)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a SimpleListAdapter then you should be able to limit the number of rows through the query.

Depends on the situation really. Do you want the user to be able to load say "10 more items" or something?

Comment: I want this limit to be 3, for example. After that, the list should be scrollable.