# Maximize visible rows in a listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-relativelayout

Here's my code for items in a list.. Suppose I'm inflating this `TextView` into the `ListView`

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/textviewItemList"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="50dp"
   android:paddingBottom="10dip"
   android:paddingLeft="10dip"
   android:paddingTop="10dip"
   android:textSize="35px" />
```

And here is my code for `ListView`, inside a `RelativeLayout` having only 3 rows are visible with others as scrollable. `RelativeLayout` having height of x3 of the height of text view...

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="150dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="15px"
  android:background="@drawable/border"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
       android:id="@+id/listview_data"
       android:layout_width="300px"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:columnWidth="30px"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:numColumns="10">
   </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But when the `ListView` is created with more than 3 items, I get shadow part when scrolling down or up, it didn't highlight all (it has some kind of shadow part or I say fading part)...

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: If you found the answer, answer it in a new post and accept it after the required waiting time. In this way, the post will be marked answered and would help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"` in your listview. Here's the second segment of your code rewritten with `cacheColorHint`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15px"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_data"
        android:layout_width="300px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnWidth="30px"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="10"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

It removes the shadow/turning the screen black problem of your `ListView`.